# Split csv file into two separate files python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file that needs to get split into two csv files (file1.csv and file2.csv). The splitting should happen - Based on column 'Name'. 70% of the rows needs to get written to file1.csv and remaining 30% into file2.csv. For example there are 10 rows named as 'AAA'. So 70% of 10 rows that means the first 7 rows of 'AAA' needs to get written into file1.csv and next 3 rows to file2.csv. Like that this needs to happen for all the names under 'Name' column. 
If getting a decimal number example 0.7 x 9 rows = 6.3. then first 6 rows (rounded) to file1.csv and remaining 3 to file2.csv
How can I get this done using a Python code? Thank you https://fil.email/FPYB1RWd

Comment: start writing some code

Comment: post what you have so far and we can help you from there

Comment: Please (a) post your code (b) format your question so it is easier to read and (c) say why you've posted a link to a download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the whole csv file and store the contents in a list. Then store similar csv data in a temp list. After storing, extract 70% of the data from the list and write it into the file and write the remaining data into another file.

```
csv_data = []
with open ('file.csv') as file:
    csv_data.append(file.read())
csv_data = (''.join(csv_data)).split("\n")
header = csv_data[0]
csv_data = csv_data[1:]
temp_list = []
add_header = True
for i in csv_data:
    if len(temp_list) == 0:
        temp_list.append(i)
    elif i.split(',')[0] == temp_list[0].split(',')[0]:
        temp_list.append(i)
    else:
        file_length = len(temp_list)
        line_count = int((0.7*file_length)+1)
        if line_count == 1:
            with open("file1.csv","a+") as file1:
                if add_header:
                    add_header = False
                    file1.write(header+'\n')
                file1.write(temp_list[0]+'\n')
        else:
            seventy_perc_lines = temp_list[:line_count]
            thirty_perc_lines = temp_list[line_count:]
            if add_header:
                seventy_perc_lines.insert(0,header)
                thirty_perc_lines.insert(0,header)
                add_header = False
            with open("file1.csv","a+") as file1:
                for j in range(len(seventy_perc_lines)):
                    file1.write(seventy_perc_lines[j]+'\n')
            if len(thirty_perc_lines) != 0:
                with open("file2.csv","a+") as file2:
                    for j in range(len(thirty_perc_lines)):
                        file2.write(thirty_perc_lines[j]+'\n')
        temp_list = []
        temp_list.append(i)
```

file1.csv

[image: first file]

file2.csv

[image: second file]

> Note: If there are only 3 lines, this code will add all the 3 lines in file1 and adds nothing to file2. You need to edit this code if you wish to change this behaviour.

Comment: thank you. But I am not getting the required output. I just get two files file1.csv and file2.csv with only headers. no data in both the files.

Comment: check if you're reading the file correctly. put a print after reading the data. I posted the answer only after testing with the csv file which you provided in your question.

Comment: The output you have shown is exactly what I need. I have attached the code https://fil.email/EP6cpvzj please let me know if I have done wrongly anywhere. Thanks again

Comment: could you attach `Alldata99.csv` along ith this?

Comment: I have modified my code. The problem was because the sample file you gave had only one column and the remaining columns were blank. So i compared the entire row. Now I changed the code to compare the first row only. Now it works fine. I have attached your sample file [here](https://fil.email/mc1fOhTS)

Comment: just wondering would you be able help with this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097740/how-to-split-csv-files-based-on-a-given-time  It would be a great help. Thanks a million

Comment: @user3535695 sure will take a look

Comment: Yes please. It would be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: make a dictionary with lists of records, keyed on the content of a given column (here I have used column no. 0), then loop on these
lists and output each single record contained in a list of records in one of two output files, according to the simple rule the OP has specified.

```
from csv import reader, writer

inp = reader(open(...))
outs = [writer(open(fnm, 'w') for fnm in ('f30', 'f70')]

column, d = 0, {}

for rec in inp0:
    d.setdefault(rec[column], []).append(rec)

for recs in d.values():
    l = round(0.7*len(recs))
    for n, rec in enumerate(recs):
        outs[n<l].writerow(rec)
```

<sup>A Boolean is a subclass of an integer, its value either 1 (when `n<l`) or 0 and can be used to index a list of `writer` s.</sup>

Here is a check of this method, using an IPython session (slightly
edited to reduce whitespace) and some artificial data

```
17:22:~ $ ipython
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
In [1]: from csv import reader, writer
   ...: from random import randrange, seed
   ...: seed(20190712)
In [2]: data = [','.join(str(randrange(10)) for _ in range(4)) for _ in range(200)]
In [3]: inf = reader(data)
In [4]: of1 = writer(open('dele1', 'w')); of2 = writer(open('dele2', 'w'))
In [5]: d = {}
In [6]: for record in inf:
   ...:     d.setdefault(record[0], []).append(record)
   ...: for key, records in d.items():
   ...:     l1 = round(0.7*len(records))
   ...:     for n, record in enumerate(records):
   ...:         (of1 if n<l1 else of2).writerow(records)
In [7]: Ctrl-D
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?
17:23:~ $ wc -l dele?
  140 dele1
   60 dele2
  200 total
17:24:~ $ rm dele?
17:24:~ $
```

As you can see, the first file gets 70% of the original records while
the second one gets the remaining 30%.

Comment: Thank you. But its not working. I am getting only one csv file which is declared by of1. And that file is same as input csv file. data has not split.

Answer (score -1):

"""
put your original file name in place of your_file_name
Use this function and the function will split the csv file and save it.
you can change split percent to get different file sizes
"""

```py
def split_csv("your_file_name.csv"):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("your_file_name.csv")
    split_percent = 0.7
    df_length = int(len(df)*split_percent)
    df1 = df.iloc[:df_length,:]
    df2 = df.iloc[df_length:,:]
    df1.to_csv("file1.csv")
    df2.to_csv("file2.csv")
```