# Capture all csv files within all subfolders in main directory - Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, glob

Below code is used to split csv files based on a given time value. The problem is this code won't capture all the csv files. For example inside TT1 folder there are several subfolders.And those subfolders have folders inside them. And within those sub-sub-folders there are csv files. When I give the path as path='/root/Desktop/TT1 it wont process all the files within those sub-sub-folders. How can I fix this please.

AFTER @Serafeim 's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57110519/5025009), I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

path = '/root/Desktop/TT1/'
mystep = 0.4

#define the function
def data_splitter(df, name):
    max_time = df['Time'].max() # get max value of Time for the current csv file (df)
    myrange= np.arange(0, max_time, mystep) # build the threshold range
    for k in range(len(myrange)):
        # build the upper values 
        temp = df[(df['Time'] >= myrange[k]) & (df['Time'] < myrange[k] + mystep)]
        temp.to_csv("/root/Desktop/T1/{}_{}.csv".format(name, k))

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    name = os.path.split(filename)[1] # get the name of the file
    data_splitter(df, name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get automatically all the subfolders and change the path:
If all the subfolders start with "Sub":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

path = '/root/Desktop/TT1/'
mystep = 0.4

#define the function
def data_splitter(df, name):
    max_time = df['Time'].max() # get max value of Time for the current csv file (df)
    myrange= np.arange(0, max_time, mystep) # build the threshold range
    for k in range(len(myrange)):
        # build the upper values 
        temp = df[(df['Time'] >= myrange[k]) & (df['Time'] < myrange[k] + mystep)]
        temp.to_csv("/root/Desktop/T1/{}_{}.csv".format(name, k))

# use os.walk(path) on the main path to get ALL subfolders inside path
for root,dirs,_ in os.walk(path):
    for d in dirs:
        path_sub = os.path.join(root,d) # this is the current subfolder
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_sub, '*.csv')):
            df = pd.read_csv(filename)
            name = os.path.split(filename)[1] # get the name of the current csv file
            data_splitter(df, name)
```

Comment: Thanks but No serafeim. The subfolders have different names. And there are more than one sub folders. And inside those subfolders there folders as well. So something that captures all the csv files inside TT1 going under subfolders and folders will work

Comment: inside `'/root/Desktop/TT1/'` you have a lot of subfolder with different names. This is okay. Inside the individual subfolders do you have other subfolders?

Comment: for root, dirs,files, in os.walk(path): will work ? I am not sure how to edit the existing code if I use os.walk

Comment: Yes. Inside the individual subfolders I do  have other subfolders. And those have the csv files. And all the subfolders Does Not start with "Sub. They have different names

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now, it automatically finds all the subfolders inside `path = '/root/Desktop/TT1/'` then it gets inside each subfolder and finds all the `.csv` files. Consider accepting the answer